# how does this type of array operate in php?

Tags: php

I am facing these codes over and over again in php, how does this work in php ?

```
$data[$row['id']]
```

and

```
$options['data']=$row[0];
```

Comment: I don't understand, what aspect of these arrays is your question about? The use of strings and numbers as the array key, or the nesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Let's initialize some variables.
$row = array();
$row[0] = 999;
$row['id'] = 6;
// $row is now equal to array(0 => 999, 'id' => 6)

$data = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19);
// $data[0] is 2; $data[1] is 3.

// At this point,
$data[$row['id']] ==   // really means...
$data[6] ==            // which equals...
17;

$options['data'] = $row[0];
$options[] = 66;
$options[44] = 77;
$options[] = 88;

// $options is now equal to array('data' => 999, 0 => 66, 44 => 77, 55 => 88)
```

Arrays are just key-value pairs. Using the `$array[] =` syntax tells PHP to assign the new element a key. PHP takes the highest integer key and adds one to it to get the new key.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in PHP are more like Hashes, where they can have string based indices. I assume `$row['id']` either contains a number or a string, and then that is being used to access the value with that key.